# Can Lenovo (or other manufacturers) limit supported SSD sizes on the AMD Ryzen SOC?

Tags: ssd, bios, amd-ryzen, soc

I am looking at a 2-year-old Lenovo IdeaPad 14 laptop that comes with a Ryzen 4700U processor and a matching Ryzen SoC. According to the [Lenovo detailed specs listing](https://psref.lenovo.com/product/ideapad/ideapad_5_14are05?tab=spec), the maximum supported SSD size is 512GB, which seems rather limiting. I am wondering if this is just written this way because they sold this lower tier model with SSD only up to 512GB, or because they have somehow - and for whatever reason - put a limit in the BIOS to prevent larger SSDs from being installed. As far as I know it supports standard M.2 PCIe NVMe SSDs of both the 2242 and 2280 variety. I don't want to buy one just to experiment with installing a larger SSD...

Answer (score 0):

The PSREF document that Lenovo produces, so I would say that if you do not want to experiment (expensive!) that you should accept PSREF.

I have a Lenovo X1 with a 1 TB NVMe SSD drive and (a) I ordered it from Lenovo that way and (b) PSREF said 1 TB Max.

I got an M70 Desktop and it allows a maximum 1 TB for the main drive, I got one from my supplier and it is the same drive as the X1 .

So I expect the basic BIOS (UEFI) dictates what is the maximum disk drive and maximum memory. PSREF normally reports that very well.

Since Lenovo issues the BIOS (UEFI) updates, they really control the maximum size of devices.

Comment: It is possible for the firmware to limit what drives are compatible with the hardware (I've seen this with some HP gear), but very often its just what has been tested, and larger drives work fine. Importantly, memory size is normally limited by the CPU, not the firmware, and throwing in a hard drive that is larger will not damage it - worst case is it won't work   (I undid the downvote as I decided to answer and dont like to downvote where I answer)

Comment: That just means the OP has to do some expensive experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting thread on these systems at https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx-Edge-LaVie-Z-Flex-Notebooks/Add-a-second-SSD-in-LENOVO-IDEAPAD-5-AMD-14-14ARE05/m-p/5037701?page=3

It is quite possible a drive larger then 512GB will not work.   Its quite possible that there is a second SSD slot you can use to expand the disk.  It appears there are different versions of this model with different hardware configuration.

Crucial list a maximum 500 gig drive, which is a good indicator some/all of these systems will not work with larger drives - https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/ideapad-5-14are05

Some people have gotten 1TB drives to work - it is quite possible that some brands will work with 1TB and others won't - Most people who claimed success used Samsung 970 drives.   Specifically someone details a Samsung 970 EVO Plus 1 TB PCIe NVMe M.2 (2280) working.   If you try it and it does not work, it is unlikely to do any long term damage.   Also, you might want to ensure you are using the latest BIOS/UEFI before upgrading.

Some further web browsing revealed this - https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/IdeaPad/IdeaPad_Flex_5_14ARE05/IdeaPad_Flex_5_14ARE05_Spec.PDF

This PSREF says that the first drive (ie M.2 2242 supports/offers up to 512GB, while the seconds M.2 2280 drive supports/offers up to 1TB)

Comment: This is the specific PSREF for the machine I am looking at: https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/IdeaPad/IdeaPad_5_14ARE05?M=81YM0002US

Only one drive slot on it.